# Pulling wordpress post's img src to be background-image

Tags: php, mysql, css, wordpress, rss

Ok. So I have a wordpress plug-in that runs a cron job that reads RSS feeds, then parses the RSS feed title and excerpt into new posts.

Most of the time, each RSS 'post' that is read includes an img tag that is straight up html (ex: `<img src="localhost/img/img-1.png">`). That img is stored in a cache on my own wordpress server so it's visible without the need of the RSS server it was read from.

What I'm trying to do is to use the img tag src as the background-image for the post.

As of now, the only way I can see the image tag without loading the wordpress post, is by diving into the WPDB, finding the post and copying out the img src.

I've already tried using the post-thumbnails option, but since the image isn't loaded as a Featured Image when it's read from the RSS feed, the image isn't loaded into the Media library of the wordpress install.

My train of thought is leading me towards some way to parse the img tag src into it's own mysql table, but that is a whole bowl of noodles I'd rather avoid.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You can do this in-page using JavaScript.

Comment: @ithcy I can do lots of things in-page using JS, thanks for the reminder. Any chance you could be more specific? Hours of writing pseudo-code and looking for viable options is driving me crazy.

Comment: @canacast That wasn't my comment...

Comment: @Diodeus I can do lots of things in-page using JS, thanks for the reminder. Any chance you could be more specific? Hours of writing pseudo-code and looking for viable options is driving me crazy.

Comment: Post a bit of the related HTML and I'll see what I can do.